# Make date with month week and weekday in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000, I have:

- Year: 2015,
- Month: 01,
- Week: 4,
- Week-Day: 2

I need: 2015-01-19

I have :

- Year: 2015,
- Month: 01,
- Week: 3,
- Week-Day: 3

I need: 2015-01-13

And so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And can you show us what **you have tried** so far? Also: SQL Server **2000** is far beyond old and has not been supported for many years - **it's about time** to upgrade!

Comment: Actually i'm working with a team, where we all working in some products. 1 of the all project developed with sql 2000 (with approximate 3335 clients). We are already taking steps to update DB, but it's matter of time. Hope you get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather ambiguous what you mean by the first week of a month, but taking the common definition of the week starting on the first day, you can do this with date arithmetic.  The result is something like:

```
select convert(datetime,
               @year * 10000 + @month*100 + (@week - 1) * 7 + (@weekday - 1),
               112)
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure if SQL Server 2000 will convert the date correctly.  You might need to cast it as a string first:

```
select convert(datetime,
               cast(@year * 10000 + @month*100 + (@week - 1) * 7 + (@weekday - 1) as varchar(8)),
               112)
```

And, as the comment says, you don't want to be using unsupported software.  It is time to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you Sir, your solution working for me. Actually i'm working with a team, where we all working in some products. 1 of the all project developed with sql 2000 (with approximate 3335 clients). We are already taking steps to update DB, but it's matter of time. Hope you get this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
--SET DATEFIRST 7 --this is the default; but include & tweak as needed for your culture

declare @Year int = 2015
,@Month int = 01
,@Week int = 4
,@WeekDay int = 2
,@date date

set @date = CAST(cast(@year as nvarchar(4)) + '-' + cast(@month as nvarchar(2)) + '-01' as date)
set @date = DATEADD(day,(@week - datepart(week,@date)) * 7,@date) 
set @date = DATEADD(day,(@weekDay - datepart(weekday,@date)) % 7,@date) 

select @date --2015-01-19

select DATEPART(week,@date) --4
select DATEPART(weekday,@date) --2
```